# How to get semantic/gulp/webpack to work in electron-react-boilerplate

Tags: node.js, reactjs, gulp, webpack, semantic-ui

I am trying to port a react app to electron using [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate) but I'm using semantic-ui which suggested being set up with gulp.  electron-react-boilerplate uses webpack to handle all of its packaging and I can't get webpack +gulp to work so everything will package in the electron app.

I'm trying [this link that explains how to pipe webpack configs through gulp tasks](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html) but I'm getting an "unexpected token import" error from the webpack config.

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0", "react"],
  "plugins": ["add-module-exports"],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "presets": ["react-optimize"],
      "plugins": ["babel-plugin-dev-expression"]
    },
    "development": {
            "plugins": ["tcomb"],
      "presets": ["react-hmre"]
    },
    "test": {
      "plugins": [
        ["webpack-loaders", { "config": "webpack.config.test.js", "verbose":     false }]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

simple gulpfile.js straight from the link above:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var webpack = require('webpack-stream');
gulp.task('default', function() {
  return gulp.src('src/entry.js')
    .pipe(webpack())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

the webpack dev file is [here](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.development.js),

note some of the names are changed between this boilerplate version and my project but otherwise it's the same.

the error:

```
Configurator>gulp
[09:52:40] Using gulpfile C:\git\Configurator\gulpfile.js
[09:52:40] Starting 'default'...
[09:52:40] 'default' errored after 8.28 ms
[09:52:40] C:\git\Configurator\webpack.config.development.js:7
import webpack from 'webpack';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:513:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:417:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:409:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (C:\git\Configurator\gulpfile.js:7:18)
    at module.exports     (C:\git\Configurator\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
```

the internet tells me that getting rid of the import errors should be as simple as using the 'es2015' preset in .babelrc but it's there and it's not helping.

I can get the dev server to work in the electron app with the semantic-ui stuff after the initial gulp build for semantic, but for some reason it doesn't build into the electron package when I try to package an installer to deploy this thing.

When I run the electron app dev server through webpack it works fine though, except I get two errors:

`cannot set property exports of undefined`

and

`locals[0] does not appear to be a module object with hot module replacement API enabled`

the latter stacktrace goes back to some semantic imports in one of my react files.

I'm totally at a loss as to how to make all this stuff work together.